# Is there a more efficient method of retrieving checkbox element by clicking link within a table?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with numerous amounts of data. Within the table, there is a link within the same row to retrieve the attributes of a checkbox.

The issue I'm having is the code of actually pinpointing the checkbox element and to determine if its checked or not. So far I have code using Jquery doing what I need it to do by grabbing the `id` of the link and navigating through the row using `closest` and numerous `prev` method calls and a final `children(0)` call.

I wanted to know if there's a more efficient way of grabbing the checkbox element without having to scrub through the whole row of data? Such as only using a `data-attribute` and an `id`. So far from what I tried this is the only method I could come up with that maintained the functionality I wanted. Below is minimalist code that only alerts if the Apple checkbox is checked, just to show functionality of what I have. Also any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click', '#downloadLink', function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 var appleCheckbox = $('#' + id).closest('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev ('td').children(0);
  if(appleCheckbox.is(':checked')){
   alert("checked");
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Apple</th>
    <th>Orange</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="appleBox">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="orangeBox">
    </td>
    <td>
     Joe
    </td>
    <td>
     May
    </td>
    <td>
     Utah
    </td>
    <td>
     <a href="#" id="downloadLink"><span id="downloadId">Dload</span></a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code that generates the HTML?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Yes, I do. I have access to the script file and html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd recommend reading:

[Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton / Engineer @ Google](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

> Yes, I do. I have access to the script file and html file

I'd highly recommend creating a class container, which might look like the following (but change it to a nice name, I choose this name to make it stand out).  This container is there to scope all of your actions within an element.  By making it a class and not the TR, it allows your html to change without breaking your javascript.  (for example someone might come in and change the table from table/tr/td to bootstrap div, in which case your original code would break.

```html
<tr class="my-container-class">
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="appleBox">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="orangeBox">
  </td>
  <td>
    Joe
  </td>
  <td>
    May
  </td>
  <td>
    Utah
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" id="downloadLink"><span id="downloadId">Dload</span></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then your javascript can simply look for the container, then find whatever it is you want inside the container.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#downloadLink', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('id');
    var appleCheckbox$ = $this.parents('my-container-class'.find('[name="appleBox"]);
    if (appleCheckbox.is(':checked')) {
      alert("checked");
    }
  });
});
```

This simply uses JQuery to search for that parent container, and then find elements with the container.  All of this means that your html can change drastically but won't break your javascript (assuming your classes and input names aren't changed).

> but wouldn't you run into a problem if you had multiple rows and each checkbox for the apple column has the same name?

This code will still work even with duplicate Id (because the FOLLOWING code doesn't use Ids and shouldn't, my previous code shouldn't use an Id).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.js-downloadLink').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $container = $this.parents('.my-container-class');
    var $checkbox = $container.find('[name="appleBox"]');
    if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
      alert("is checked");
    } else {
      alert("is NOT checked");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="my-container-class">
<td>
  <input id="chkAppleBoxDownloadId" type="checkbox" name="appleBox">
</td>
<td>
  <a href="#" class="js-downloadLink"><span id="downloadId">Dload</span></a>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-container-class">
<td>
  <input id="chkAppleBoxDownloadId" type="checkbox" name="appleBox" checked>
</td>
<td>
  <a href="#" class="js-downloadLink"><span id="downloadId">Dload</span></a>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-container-class">
<td>
  <input id="chkAppleBoxDownloadId" type="checkbox" name="appleBox">
</td>
<td>
 <a href="#" class="js-downloadLink"><span id="downloadId">Dload</span></a>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-container-class">
<td>
  <input id="chkAppleBoxDownloadId" type="checkbox" name="appleBox" checked>
</td>
<td>
  <a href="#" class="js-downloadLink"><span id="downloadId">Dload</span></a>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but wouldn't you run into a problem if you had multiple rows and each checkbox for the apple column has the same name?

Comment: @King11 no because the event is contained in the element.  I'll add code to demonstrate.

Comment: Ah ok nice. I've incorporated your logic within my code and it works nicely. Thank so much for the help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation as well. This site really needs more elaborated answers like this.

Comment: @King11 I agree.  The *try this* answers really annoy me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I hope you must have unique row. Hence you can generate id chkAppleBox + DownloadId
Like : chkAppleBox1000, chkAppleBox1001 ......

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="chkAppleBoxDownloadId" type="checkbox" name="appleBox">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orangeBox">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Joe
                </td>
                <td>
                    May
                </td>
                <td>
                    Utah
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" id="downloadLink"><span id="downloadId">Dload</span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

and jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#downloadLink', function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var appleCheckbox = $('#chkAppleBox' + id);
    if(appleCheckbox.is(':checked')){
        alert("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion but I would like to not change the original element's html attributes if that can be avoided.